# QScrollArea with custom QFrame

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qscrollarea, qframe

I'm using Qt 5.8. I have my custom QFrame (call it MyQFrame), which consists of several other QWidgets and can (and will) contain other instance of my custom MyQFrame. I set minimum size for MyQFrame. MyQFrame uses QGridLayout as layout.

This MyQFrame is placed inside of QScrollArea in QTabWidget. QScrollArea is set to be resizable (`setWidgetResizable(true)`). In MyQFrame I tried to set size policy to expanding (`setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);`) but it was without effect.

This is (abstraction) how I create QTabWidget and QScrollArea:

```
QTabWidget* tabWidget = new QTabWidget();
QScrollArea* firstTab = new QScrollArea();
firstTab->setWidgetResizable(true);
tabWidget->addTab(firstTab, "first tab");
MyQFrame* myFrame1 = new MyQFrame();
firstTab->setWidget(myFrame1);
// ... adding other MyQFrames inside this one using methods in MyQFrame ...
```

I cannot get scroll area working. Instead of expanding parents of nested MyQFrames and adding scroll bar is last child getting overlaped by other MyQFrames. Looks like I'm missing something like `setWidgetResizable` for MyQFrames, but this method is only in QScrollArea. I have no idea what should I try now. I'm still pretty new to this.

It should be more clear from image below.

[image: overlaping]

Comment: I tried to set minimal size to some crazy value in MyQFrame (3000x3000) and then scroll bars appeared. However MyQFrames were overlaping pretty bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said, I use QGridLayout in MyQFrame. I had to set size constraint for this layout to minimum size like this: `layout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMinimumSize);`. Now it's working how I wanted.